# Update label from nested function called from Task API in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, properties, task

I am performing some background task using this class

```
class Download extends Task{
     protected Object call() throws Exception {
        try {
            updateMessage("Establishing Connection");
            DownloadHelper downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper();
            downloadHelper.performTask();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This Task in turn calls DownloadHelper to perform some task.

```
class DownloadHelper{
    public DownloadHelper(){
    }

    public void performTask(){
    ----
    ----
    }
}
```

Is there a way to update the status message of the Task API (updateMessage()) from the DownloadHelper class.?

Comment: Pass a reference to the enclosing `Task` as a parameter to the `DownloadHelper` constructor?

Comment: That results in hight coupling....I wish to know to know if it could be done with Property in javafx

Comment: Pass a reference to the `message` property of the enclosing `Task` as a parameter to the `DownloadHelper` constructor?

Comment: "message" is a private final property which cann not be updated from anywhere except 'updateMessage()'. So even if I pass the property, it cannot be set from there.

Comment: Pass a `java.util.function.Consumer` representing your implementation of `updateMessage()` in the enclosing Task as a parameter to the `DownloadHelper` constructor?

Comment: Thanks it worked

Answer (score 4):

The expedient approach is to pass a reference to the `Download` task as a parameter to the `DownloadHelper` constructor. To minimize coupling, you can instead pass a reference to your implementation of `updateMessage()` as a parameter of type [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), "an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result."

```
DownloadHelper helper = new DownloadHelper(this::updateMessage);
```

Your helper's implementation of `performTask()` can then ask the `updater` to `accept()` messages as needed.

```
Consumer<String> updater;

public DownloadHelper(Consumer<String> updater) {
    this.updater = updater;
}

public void performTask() {
    updater.accept("Helper message");
}
```

A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32116938/230513).

[image]

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708923/230513
 */
public class MessageTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("MessageTest");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Label label = new Label();
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 120);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        Download task = new Download();
        task.messageProperty().addListener((Observable o) -> {
            label.setText(task.getMessage());
        });
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    private static class Download extends Task<String> {

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            updateMessage("Establishing connection");
            DownloadHelper helper = new DownloadHelper(this::updateMessage);
            helper.performTask();
            return "MessageTest";
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateMessage(String message) {
            super.updateMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private static class DownloadHelper {

        Consumer<String> updater;

        public DownloadHelper(Consumer<String> updater) {
            this.updater = updater;
        }

        public void performTask() {
            updater.accept("Helper message");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```