# Need to multithread a unirest request and wait for answer

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, unirest

I'm struggling a bit with a multithreaded problem. I need to send a request via `sendRESTRequest(jsonRequest)`, but I dont't want to block the UI thread so `maskerPane.setVisible` will be executed.

I could use a JavaFX `Task` but then I have to code my `currentValueLabel.setText` (etc) in that thread. But because I'm reusing the `sendRESTRequest(jsonRequest)` method I will blow up my code with a lot of useless lines.

Is it possible to execute `sendRESTRequest` on antoher thread, wait for the result of `Unirest.post` and use the returned `HttpResponse jsonResponse` for further processing?

Currently I'm using this code:

```
@FXML
protected void searchButtonAction() {
    maskerPane.setVisible(true);

    cardNumber = cardNumberTextField.getText();

    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject()
    .put("id", cardNumber)
    .put("trans", 20);


            //
            // How to put this asynchronus, but wait for the answer before continuing to System.out.println(loyaltyResponse.toString());
            //
    JSONObject loyaltyResponse = sendRESTRequest(jsonRequest);
            //
            //
            //

    System.out.println(loyaltyResponse.toString());

    currentValueLabel.setText(loyaltyResponse.getString("amount").replace(".", ",") + " Currency");
    maximumValueLabel.setText(loyaltyResponse.getString("balanceMax").replace(".", ",") + " Currency");

    maskerPane.setVisible(false);
}

private JSONObject sendRESTRequest(JSONObject jsonRequest) {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://myurl/")
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .body(jsonRequest)
        .asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonResponse.getBody().getObject();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Arrange for the GUI to listen to the `value` property of a notional `Task<JSONObject>`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44056730/230513) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718846/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved it via

```
@FXML
protected void searchButtonAction() {
    maskerPane.setVisible(true);

    cardNumber = cardNumberTextField.getText();

    JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject()
    .put("id", cardNumber)
    .put("trans", 20);
    Task<JSONObject> jsonRequestTask = new Task<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public JSONObject call() {
            return sendRESTRequest(jsonRequest);
        }
    };

    jsonRequestTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        JSONObject loyaltyResponse = jsonRequestTask.getValue();

        currentValueLabel.setText(loyaltyResponse.getString("amount").replace(".", ",") + " Currency");
        maximumValueLabel.setText(loyaltyResponse.getString("balanceMax").replace(".", ",") + " Currency");

        maskerPane.setVisible(false);
    }

    jsonRequestTask.setOnFailed(event -> {
        maskerPane.setVisible(false);
    });

    new Thread(jsonRequestTask).start();
}

private JSONObject sendRESTRequest(JSONObject jsonRequest) {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = null;
    try {
        jsonResponse = Unirest.post("http://myurl/")
        .header("accept", "application/json")
        .body(jsonRequest)
        .asJson();
    } catch (UnirestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonResponse.getBody().getObject();
}
```

Works fine. Thanks for your help.