# I want to loop through a list and want to show a progressBar while looping through that list

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

i have two different classes into two different files
One class is for ProgressBar

```
public class ProgressBarController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ProgressBar progressBar;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

}
```

and another class is where i want to loop through the list and want to update the progress on the basis of that list

```
public class AnotherClass {
    public Envelope function(List<Invoice> invoiceList) throws IOException {
        for(Invoice invoiceModel : invoiceList) {
            // update the progressBar and do some work


        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create a new thread

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
     @Override
     public Void call() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           // do some work
           updateProgress(i + 1, 100);
           try {
          Thread.sleep(200);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
        }
        return null;
     }
};
progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.start();
```

but this was not working either my progress bar is not updating and if it is then it is updating after complete all other task.

I want to update the progressBar on the basis of data in for loop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the code a [mre]. What you've shown us is the right idea. But if the `ProgressBar` is not updating, then the problem is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Progress Bar is updating if I define the Task in ProgressBarController, but I want to update the progressBar with my for loop but i am not getting any idea how to do this

Comment: Absent more context, it's hard to offer more specific guidance, but you may be able to adapt this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718846/230513) using a `BiConsumer`.

Comment: Then you need to adapt the code so that `function` has a way to report progress. It doesn't need to directly be aware of the `Task` class; as noted, you could use a `BiConsumer` as a callback that `function` invokes periodically, where the callback implementation calls `updateProgress`. That of course means that `function` would need to be called from within a `Task` implementation. And the `ProgressBarController` _instance_ needs some sort of access to the `Task` so that it can bind the progress bar's property.

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: This is just a guess based on your limited code. Do not try to update the `ProgressBar` in the `Task`. Use the `Task's` `setOnSucceeded` to update the `ProgressBar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that shows how to update the `ProgressBar` for a list of `Tasks`. My guess is that What I have in the `Button` is similar to what you should have in `for(Invoice invoiceModel : invoiceList)`.

**Key Code**

```
task.setOnSucceeded((event) -> {
    System.out.println("finished working on url " + t.toString());                    
    bar.setProgress(((float)counter.incrementAndGet()) / urlsList.size());
    System.out.println("Counter: " + counter    + "\t list size: " + urlsList.size());
});
```

**Full Code**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Creates a FlowPane and adds some rectangles inside. A LayoutAnimator is set
 * to observe the contents of the FlowPane for layout changes.
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });
    
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        List<URL> urlsList = getURLs();

        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(0);
        
        Button btnProcessUrls = new Button("Process URLs");
        btnProcessUrls.setOnAction((onAction) -> {
            List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList();

            urlsList.forEach((t) -> {
                Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call() {
                        System.out.println("I starting working on URL " + t.toString());
                        //Simulate long running task
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000 ;i++) {
                            //System.out.print("working on url " + t.toString() + "\r");
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                task.setOnSucceeded((event) -> {
                    System.out.println("finished working on url " + t.toString());                    
                    bar.setProgress(((float)counter.incrementAndGet()) / urlsList.size());
                    System.out.println("Counter: " + counter    + "\t list size: " + urlsList.size());
                });
                
                taskList.add(task);
            });
            
            taskList.forEach(exec::submit);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(bar, btnProcessUrls);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Flow Layout Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public List<URL> getURLs() {
        List<URL> urls = new ArrayList();
        simulateQueringDbForUrlStrings().forEach((t) -> {
            try {
                urls.add(new URL(t));
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        });

        return urls;
    }

    public List<String> simulateQueringDbForUrlStrings() {
        String dbResults = """
                           http://www.youtube.com
                           http://www.facebook.com
                           http://www.baidu.com
                           http://www.yahoo.com
                           http://www.amazon.com
                           http://www.wikipedia.org
                           http://www.qq.com
                           http://www.google.co.in
                           http://www.twitter.com
                           http://www.live.com
                           http://www.taobao.com
                           http://www.bing.com
                           http://www.instagram.com
                           http://www.weibo.com
                           http://www.sina.com.cn
                           http://www.linkedin.com
                           http://www.yahoo.co.jp
                           http://www.msn.com
                           http://www.vk.com
                           http://www.google.de
                           http://www.yandex.ru
                           http://www.hao123.com
                           http://www.google.co.uk
                           http://www.reddit.com
                           http://www.ebay.com
                           http://www.google.fr
                           http://www.t.co
                           http://www.tmall.com
                           http://www.google.com.br
                           http://www.360.cn
                           http://www.sohu.com
                           http://www.amazon.co.jp
                           http://www.pinterest.com
                           http://www.netflix.com
                           http://www.google.it
                           http://www.google.ru
                           http://www.microsoft.com
                           http://www.google.es
                           http://www.wordpress.com
                           http://www.gmw.cn
                           http://www.tumblr.com
                           http://www.paypal.com
                           http://www.blogspot.com
                           http://www.imgur.com
                           http://www.stackoverflow.com
                           http://www.aliexpress.com
                           http://www.naver.com
                           http://www.ok.ru
                           http://www.apple.com
                           http://www.github.com
                           http://www.chinadaily.com.cn
                           http://www.imdb.com
                           http://www.google.co.kr
                           http://www.fc2.com
                           http://www.jd.com
                           http://www.blogger.com
                           http://www.163.com
                           http://www.google.ca
                           http://www.whatsapp.com
                           http://www.amazon.in
                           http://www.office.com
                           http://www.tianya.cn
                           http://www.google.co.id
                           http://www.youku.com
                           http://www.rakuten.co.jp
                           http://www.craigslist.org
                           http://www.amazon.de
                           http://www.nicovideo.jp
                           http://www.google.pl
                           http://www.soso.com
                           http://www.bilibili.com
                           http://www.dropbox.com
                           http://www.xinhuanet.com
                           http://www.outbrain.com
                           http://www.pixnet.net
                           http://www.alibaba.com
                           http://www.alipay.com
                           http://www.microsoftonline.com
                           http://www.booking.com
                           http://www.googleusercontent.com
                           http://www.google.com.au
                           http://www.popads.net
                           http://www.cntv.cn
                           http://www.zhihu.com
                           http://www.amazon.co.uk
                           http://www.diply.com
                           http://www.coccoc.com
                           http://www.cnn.com
                           http://www.bbc.co.uk
                           http://www.twitch.tv
                           http://www.wikia.com
                           http://www.google.co.th
                           http://www.go.com
                           http://www.google.com.ph
                           http://www.doubleclick.net
                           http://www.onet.pl
                           http://www.googleadservices.com
                           http://www.accuweather.com
                           http://www.googleweblight.com
                           http://www.answers.yahoo.com
                           http://www.youtube.com
                           http://www.facebook.com
                           http://www.baidu.com
                           http://www.yahoo.com
                           http://www.amazon.com
                           http://www.wikipedia.org
                           http://www.qq.com
                           http://www.google.co.in
                           http://www.twitter.com
                           http://www.live.com
                           http://www.taobao.com
                           http://www.bing.com
                           http://www.instagram.com
                           http://www.weibo.com
                           http://www.sina.com.cn
                           http://www.linkedin.com
                           http://www.yahoo.co.jp
                           http://www.msn.com
                           http://www.vk.com
                           http://www.google.de
                           http://www.yandex.ru
                           http://www.hao123.com
                           http://www.google.co.uk
                           http://www.reddit.com
                           http://www.ebay.com
                           http://www.google.fr
                           http://www.t.co
                           http://www.tmall.com
                           http://www.google.com.br
                           http://www.360.cn
                           http://www.sohu.com
                           http://www.amazon.co.jp
                           http://www.pinterest.com
                           http://www.netflix.com
                           http://www.google.it
                           http://www.google.ru
                           http://www.microsoft.com
                           http://www.google.es
                           http://www.wordpress.com
                           http://www.gmw.cn
                           http://www.tumblr.com
                           http://www.paypal.com
                           http://www.blogspot.com
                           http://www.imgur.com
                           http://www.stackoverflow.com
                           http://www.aliexpress.com
                           http://www.naver.com
                           http://www.ok.ru
                           http://www.apple.com
                           http://www.github.com
                           http://www.chinadaily.com.cn
                           http://www.imdb.com
                           http://www.google.co.kr
                           http://www.fc2.com
                           http://www.jd.com
                           http://www.blogger.com
                           http://www.163.com
                           http://www.google.ca
                           """;

        String[] urls = dbResults.split("\n");

        List<String> urlsStringList = new ArrayList();
        for (String url : urls) {
            urlsStringList.add(url.strip());
        }

        return urlsStringList;
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]